# How to deploy java gradle application on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, web-deployment, procfile

Please help to deploy my application on Heroku. 
Getting error message from Heroku *

> "Application Error. An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the
>   application owner, check your logs for details."

Here log from Heroku:

```
2016-07-21T22:11:30.966800+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation 
started 2016-07-21T22:11:30.773385+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by 
zzheads@gmail.com 2016-07-21T22:11:56.184847+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error 
code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=zzheads-countries.herokuapp.com request_id=a03c9276-b038-4f9f-8e6d-
5f29f14b441 fwd="5.3.141.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My gradle build file:

```
group 'com.zzheads'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
}

task stage {
    dependsOn build
}
```

And my Proc file:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/countries-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: how do you run your app locally?

Comment: From IntellyJ IDEA IDE, just click Run 'countries [bootRun]' ..

Answer (score 3):

Your build probably generates an executable JAR file in the directory `build/libs`. Try this in your `Procfile`:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/countries-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You can test it locally by running:

```
$ ./gradlew stage
$ heroku local
```

Comment: Same error message, same logs. Tryed test it locally: E:\Projects\countries>gradlew stage
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:findMainClass
:startScripts
:installApp
The installApp task has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0. Please use the installDist task instead.
:stage

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.13 secs
E:\Projects\countries>heroku local
[WARN] No ENV file found
12:04:46 web.1   |  Error: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
12:04:46 web.1   Exited with exit code 1

Comment: The error about `$JAVA_OPTS` is because you are on windows. you'll need to create a `Procfile.windows` with a windows formatted command and run `heroku local -f Procfile.windows`

Comment: Have you tried it on Heroku? you will probably have to run `heroku ps:scale web=1` to get the app up now that it's crashed.

Comment: Yes, I've tryed this on Heroku as wrote above. Getting same error, same logs. How I can test it locally? gradlew stage -> Build successfull, but "heroku local" runs with errors

Answer (score 0):

I think that Heroku is not able to find your `.jar` because when it does not find a version property, the gradle buildpack just uses its own build id. So your `.jar` is not found under the filename in your procfile. You can set the following:

```
jar{
  baseName = 'countries-'
  version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

so Heroku picks up on those variables. Note that if you're using Spring Boot 2.*, the plugin disables the `jar` tasks, and adds a `bootJar` task on which you then have to set these to variables.

With that, the platform should be able to find your artifact just fine.

Also, running `heroku logs -a <your-app-name-here> -t` you'll get some more information about the status of your app while debugging